# Change the sprite when mouse over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Inside the script code I want add the possibility to change its sprite.  So the player mouseover the sprite,it changes into the other sprite already added to the project.  Can you provide me a sample code to do this?

```
var newSprite : Sprite;
function Start () {
print(gameObject.name);
}
void OnMouseEnter() 
{
 print("hii  detected");
 //targetGui.texture = hoverTex;
 GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = newSprite;          
}

 void OnMouseExit() 

{

 }
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Does your sprite get changed correctly when `OnMouseEnter` is triggered? Or are you wanting the sprite to change back when `OnMouseExit` is triggered?

Comment: when an image is clicked and dragged on to the scene ,when mouse placed on it , mouse over is not detecting. why ..this is my issue....  but when iam trying on gu texture it is  working fine...  wt s the issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make both of the sprite as gameObjects. Then disable the Sprite Renderer of the `newSprite` object and attach the script to the current Sprite (first sprite).

```
public GameObject newSprite;
private Vector3 currentSpritePosition;

void OnMouseEnter(){
  //getting the current position of the current sprite if ever it can move;
  currentSpritePosition = transform.position;

  //then make it invisible
  renderer.enabled = false;

  //give the new sprite the position of the latter
  newSprite.transform.position = currentSpritePosition;

  //then make it visible
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = true;
}

void OnMouseExit(){
  //just the reverse process
  renderer.enabled = true;
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
}
```

You can also diable at start as follows:

```
void Start(){
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
}
```

EDIT: You should add a collider to the current sprite for the `OnMouseOver` and `OnMouseExit` to work.

Comment: Are you using it as Javascript or C# script? As the code is meant for C#.